# detect how many lines in char array

Tags: c, strtok

```
char linesinfo[] = "Place\n Some\n Text\n Here";

char pch = strtok(linesinfo,"\n");

int total_line = 0;
while(pch  != NULL)
{

     pch = strtok(NULL,"\n");
     total_line++;
}
```

question: do I have to use total_line-1 or just use total_line?

Comment: what ever you are trying to do ..but pch should be a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `strtok()` for this, it will *modify* the string which is not needed for the problem you're trying to solve, and generally dangerous and bad.

Just loop through and count the linefeeds directly:

```
int total_line = 0;
const char *str;
for(str = linesinfo; *str; ++str)
  total_line += *str == '\n';
```

This works since C's comparison operators always generate 0 for false and 1 for true. This is distinct from the fact that e.g. `if` will interpet *any* non-zero value as being true, and an incredibly useful feature.

Of course, the above can be re-written to be less terse in any number of ways, for instance:

```
  if( *str == '\n' )
    ++total_line;
```

which may or may not be faster, depending on your exact circumstances. Sometimes the original code might be faster if the compiler generates branch-less code for it, I imagine that's harder for the explicit `if`.